# XPath Expression to get adjacent nodes conditionally

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml file with some content like the following:

```
<p>
    <r>
        <t xml:space="preserve">Reading is easier, </t>
    </r>
    <r>
        <fldChar fldCharType="begin"/>
    </r>
    <r>
        <instrText xml:space="preserve"> REF _Ref516568558 \r \p \h </instrText>
    </r>
    <r>
        <fldChar fldCharType="separate"/>
    </r>
    <r>
        <t>This is all the text I want to capture</t>
    </r>
    <r>
        <fldChar fldCharType="end"/>
    </r>
    <r>
        <t xml:space="preserve">, in the new Reading view </t>
    </r>
    <r>
        <fldChar fldCharType="begin"/>
    </r>
    <r>
        <instrText xml:space="preserve"> REF _Not516755367 \r \h </instrText>
    </r>
    <r>
        <fldChar fldCharType="separate"/>
    </r>
    <r>
        <t>But not this...</t>
    </r>
    <r>
        <fldChar fldCharType="end"/>
    </r>
    <r>
        <t xml:space="preserve"> Some other text... </t>
    </r>
</p>
```

I know that I can use the XPath expression `//instrText[contains(text(), '_Ref')]` to get `<instrText xml:space="preserve"> REF _Ref516568558 \r \p \h </instrText>`.

Now what I want to get is the text within `t` nodes between `<fldChar fldCharType="begin"/>` and `<fldChar fldCharType="end"/>` if between these two tags there is a `instrText` with text that contains `'_Ref'` ie `instrText[contains(text(), '_Ref']`.

Based on this, from the example xml, I would expect only: `<t>This is all the text I want to capture</t>` to be returned.

Can this be done with a single XPath 1.0 expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using: `//p/r[preceding-sibling::r[fldChar/@fldCharType='begin'] and following-sibling::r[fldChar/@fldCharType='end']][instrText[contains(text(), '_Ref')]]/following-sibling::r[t][1]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `p/r[preceding-sibling::r[fldChar/@fldCharType='begin'] and following-sibling::r[fldChar/@fldCharType='end']]/t[contains(., '_Ref')]`

Comment: This is not currently working but I can see where it is going... I'll continue experimenting with it. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: This has still got a problem... `But not this` is still returned because preceding-sibling checks all preceding siblings...

Comment: Why should `But not this` not be shown? Can you add in the original post what the expected output should be?